# scribus: adding and naming spot color, which then can be seen in a pdf after export

Tags: color, print-design, pdf, scribus, spot-color

In the current `Scribus` version 1.5.5.svn, I am adding an additional spot color as follows:

```
Edit --> Color and Fills... --> Add --> name and select "is spot color" --> OK
```

I can then use this color on certain elements and export my project as e.g. PDF. But when I load the PDF it does show me another name for the color: `FromPDF#009ee3`. Also it doesn't show me that I have marked it as overprinting.

I need this for partial refinement in printing. Does anybody know a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the issue. When exporting the `pdf`, you have to select `output intended for printer` as seen below in the picture, else the color (doesn't matter if you have made it a spot color or named it) will not be shown as it needs to be shown in the pdf.

[image]

Comment: Realize that the PDF **viewing application** makes a world of difference. Since most average users are *never* using spot colors, most user-level PDF viewers are not designed to recognize or show spot colors. This includes things like ALL browser plug ins, Apple's Preview, etc.. You need a more robust viewer such as Reader or Acrobat.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did something "wrong".

Colors named "FromPDF..." are created when importing things from a PDF.

Without seeing the .sla file and the .pdf it's hard to say where the problem is, but I would that you did not apply the spot color to the given shape. For some reason...

If you still have no clue what did go wrong, you can create a new file with a simple shape, create a spot color, apply the spot color, export it to PDF. If you the result is now correct, compare what you did in the two projects.

If you get again a wrong result, please share the sample .sla and .pdf so that we can see what you did and we can try ourselves.